# Display available Wi-Fi networks names both Android and iOS by using capacitor in ionicVue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6, ionic-vue

I want to show all available Wi-Fi network names in both Android and iOS by using capacitor (or)
any other dependency in ionic Vue.
Also Enable and disable the Wi-Fi network from Ionic Vue Capacitor.
Should also Enable and Disable with Bluetooth.

Comment: Take a look this documentation: [wifi-wizard-2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/wifi-wizard-2)